# R: visreg for gam with interactive variables

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

Hi I am currently estimating happiness and age using the gam model.
My command for the regression is

```
    fit <- gam(happy ~ s(age) + s(age, by=nochild) ,data=happy)
```

and I would like to visualise the estimated effect of the interactive variable "s(age):nochild" using `visreg`. I am struggling to do so as only the estimation for age and nochild has shown up when using

```
    visreg(fit)
```

I want the graph to look like this

- Y axis : s(age):nochild
- X axis : age

However, I am not sure how to do this with `visreg` or is there any other commands that can help to do this?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Shouldn't this be easy with `expand.grid` and `predict`?

Answer (score 1):

I got the code that I need now so I think I might share this.

```
    plot(fit, select=2, main="No Children")
```